# Zuul / eureka in google cloud redirect to internal IP instead of external , how to fix it?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud

I am deploying a spring-cloud application at google-cloud. I have a reserved static external IP, and a static internal IP. The application is using Zuul with Eureka.    When I deploy it on a server other then gcloud , everything works fine ( zuul fetches the URLs to route from the Eureka discovery.

But when I try it on gloud (with debian 9),  zuul fetches the URLs with the internal IP

Here an excerpt of the Zuul config:

```
zuul:
routes:
    legacy-service:
        path: /legacy-service/**
        serviceId: legacy-service
        stripPrefix: false
```

On other servers (f.e. running Ubuntu 18), when I call

```
https://<IP>/legacy-service
```

it works fine and resolves to

```
https://<IP>:8094/data-service/login
```

At Gcloud , when I call

```
https://<IP>/legacy-service
```

it resolves to

```
https://<INTERNAL-IP>:8094/data-service/login
```

Any hint how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: You're either going to have to give spring cloud some hints when it guesses what to advertise https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#ignore-network-interfaces or tell eureka explicitly the ip to use using `eureka.instance.hostname`.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said and it works now. A the Eureka service I added `spring:  
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
      - nic0              
      - default `   ,   and set the IP too: ` eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: `34.x.x.x` .  At all other services I added `eureka: instance:  preferIpAddress: true
                   ip-address: @edge-server-ip@`